# Carrierwave; multiple uploaders or just one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I have a **post** model and a **podcast** model. Both models have an attribute titled: *image*. I'm using one [Carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) uploader (named ImageUploader) to handle both models. I have two questions before I go into production.

**Dumb question**:

Is it ok to use the same uploader for two different models when they both have the same attribute name for their file attachements?  *sorry if it seems obvious*

**Main question**:

I want to create three versions of each blog post image (thumb, large, sepia) and only 1 version of each podcast image (thumb).

Do I need to use two uploaders now or can I namespace with the one that I'm already using?

Again it probably seems obvious. *I could probably have written the second uploader in the time its taken me to ask these questions*

Comment: it's a very very good question

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use the same uploader on different models even if they have different attribute names. e.g.

```
class Post
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end

class Podcast
  mount_uploader :photo, ImageUploader
end
```

Whether or not you'd want to is a different matter.  In your case, I'd create different uploaders for each model, because they have different requirements.  You can always use subclasses if you want to keep your code dry:

```
class ImageUploader < Carrierwave::Uploader::Base; end  # thumbnail
class PostImageUploader < ImageUploader; end  # thumbnail (from superclass), large & sepia
class PodcastImageUploader < ImageUploader; end # thumbnail (from superclass)
```